# UTF-8 al leer un fichero .txt en Java

Tags: java, utf-8

Quisiera que se imprimieran los caracteres "extraños" del tipo **acentos o ñ**, por ejemplo pero tengo el problema de que no se imprime el carácter con **UTF-8.** ¿Cómo puedo solventar el problema?

Que se visualicen bien los caracteres y que al guardar también se guarde con el **UTF-8.**

**Código:**

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class formAbrirGuardarTXT extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    JFileChooser seleccionar = new JFileChooser();
    File fichero;
    FileInputStream entrada;
    FileOutputStream salida;

    public formAbrirGuardarTXT() {
        initComponents();
    }

    public String abrirFichero(File fichero) {
        String documento = "";
        try {
            entrada = new FileInputStream(fichero);
            int ascci;
            while ((ascci = entrada.read()) != -1) {
                char c = (char) ascci;
                documento += c;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return documento;
    }

    public String guardarFichero(File fichero, String documento) {
        String mensaje = null;
        try {
            salida = new FileOutputStream((fichero), "utf-8"); //error
            byte[] b = documento.getBytes();
            salida.write(b);
            mensaje = "Fichero guardado correctamente.";
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return mensaje;
    }


    private void button_abrirActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             
        if (seleccionar.showDialog(null, "Abrir fichero") == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            fichero = seleccionar.getSelectedFile();
            if (fichero.canRead()) {
                if (fichero.getName().endsWith("txt")) {
                    String documento = abrirFichero(fichero);
                    area_fichero.setText(documento);
                } else {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Archivo no compatible.");
                }
            }
        }
    }                                            

    private void button_guardarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                               
        if (seleccionar.showDialog(null, "Guardar fichero") == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            fichero = seleccionar.getSelectedFile();
            if (fichero.getName().endsWith("txt")) {
                String documento = area_fichero.getText();
                String mensaje = guardarFichero(fichero, documento);
                if (mensaje != null) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, mensaje);
                } else {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Archivo no compatible.");
                }
            } else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Guardar documento de texto.");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

En cambio, si pongo `salida = new FileOutputStream(fichero);` sí me lee la línea pero no lee los caracteres extraños.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para abrir el fichero y mostrarlo en en el textArea podrias hacerlo asi, he modificado el metodo `abrirFichero`

```
public String abrirFichero(File fichero) {
        String documento = "";
        try {
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(fichero), StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
            //entrada = new FileInputStream(fichero); Comento esto y uso el BufferedReader para indicarle el UTF

            int ascci;

            while ((ascci = in.read()) != -1) {
                char c = (char) ascci;
                documento += c;
            }

            in.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return documento;
    }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para guardarlo cambie tambien el tipo de dato que usabas

```
public String guardarFichero(File fichero, String documento) {
        String mensaje = null;
        Writer out = null;
        try {
            out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
                    new FileOutputStream(fichero), "UTF-8"));
            try {
                out.append(documento);
                out.flush();
                out.close();
                mensaje = "Se guardo con exito";
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                System.out.println(ex);
            }
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        return mensaje;
    }
```

Y básicamente eso fue lo que modifiqué.